# Cannot get SocketPermission to work with RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I have an RMI application and I'm trying to get the policy files right. Everything is fine when I set the permissions as:

```
grant codeBase "file:MyJar.jar" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

But this is too liberal for a production environment. When I change to:

```
grant codeBase "file:MyJar.jar" {
    permission java.security.SocketPermission "*:1024-", "accept, resolve";
};
```

I get the AccessControlException as below. I thought I covered the permission needed?

```
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 127.0.0.1:63014 accept,resolve)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkAccept(SecurityManager.java:1157)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.checkAcceptPermission(TCPTransport.java:636)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.checkAcceptPermission(TCPTransport.java:275)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:158)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

**Edit:**
After running with `-Djava.security.debug=access,failure` and changing the `"*:1024"` to `"localhost:1024"`:

```
access: domain that failed ProtectionDomain  (file:MyJar.jar <no signer certificates>)
 sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6bbc4459
 <no principals>
 java.security.Permissions@281acd47 (
 (unresolved java.security.SocketPermission localhost:1024- accept, resolve)
 (java.io.FilePermission MyJar.jar read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission line.separator read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission apple.laf.* read,write)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission java.vm.version read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission java.vm.specification.version read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission java.vm.specification.vendor read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission java.vendor.url read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission java.vm.name read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission os.name read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission java.vm.vendor read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission com.apple.macos.useScreenMenuBar read,write)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission path.separator read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission java.specification.name read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission os.version read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission com.apple.hwaccel read,write)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission mrj.version read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission os.arch read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission apple.awt.* read,write)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission java.class.version read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission java.version read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission file.separator read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission java.vendor read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission java.vm.specification.name read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission java.specification.version read)
 (java.util.PropertyPermission java.specification.vendor read)
 (java.lang.RuntimePermission stopThread) 
 (java.lang.RuntimePermission exitVM)
 (java.net.SocketPermission localhost:1024- listen,resolve)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I typed the `SocketPermission` into the policy file wrong. It should be `java.net.SocketPermission` instead of `java.security.SocketPermission`. That's why it said it was unresolved.

Answer (score 3):

Run it with -Djava.security.debug=access,failure to see exactly what's going on. I'm not convinced that * by itself is a valid host specification in a SocketPermission. I'm also not clear why you're using a SecurityManager at all for communications within the local host.

Comment: It tells me '(unresolved java.security.SocketPermission *:1024- accept, resolve)' I cannot find a way to fix it. Any searches point me to the UnresolvedPermission class descriptions, which is unhelpful or I don't understand sth.

Comment: According to docs "*" is a wildcard. "127.0.0.1" gives the same error. The application will run across the network. I'm just testing it on a single machine for now.

Comment: @MaciejTrybiło According to the docs '*' is a wildcard component of a DNS name actually. The dump also tells you what protection domain was in effect at the point of the failure, and what permissions it contained. That will tell you whether you have even loaded your .policy file.

Comment: I've changed the * to localhost and put the full failed access dump into the edit.

Comment: @MaciejTrybiło "(unresolved java.security.SocketPermission localhost:1024- accept, resolve)" provides the key, along with the last line of the domain dump, which shows that the only SocketPermission granted is not 'accept, resolve', but 'listen, resolve'. So either your .policy file doesn't contain what you think it does, or it didn't get loaded.

Comment: I've found the problem, see my answer. Thanks for your time. I've upvoted. BTW, the "*" works well!